# nextjs debugger not properly listening inside docker container

Tags: node.js, debugging, next.js

I have the feeling that my debugger doesn't do anything, even thou it is connected:
[image]

I am trying to connect via my visual studio code to the debugger to debug my nextjs app.
But it ignores all the breakpoints..
My configuration looks fine to me:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9229,
        "address": "localhost",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "skipFiles": [
          "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
          "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please @marius, I have the same issue. Please, have you found the solution ?

Comment: didnt find a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

I have a alternative solution. You can use the browser debugger. You have the possibility to put breakpoints and many others. After many hours spending to find a solution, I decide to use it and everything going well now. Here is a screenshot of the debugger and breakpoints that I had put.

[image]